# How do I install older version of JDK on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, mechanicalturk, java-5

I need to install JDK 5 for testing Amazon mechanical turk APIs (which is not fully compatible with JDK 6). On Apple's website, I can only find the latest JDK. Is there a way to get older versions of JDKs for Mac?

Comment: First look in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/ .    It may already be installed.

Comment: @StevenD.Majewski Thanks! I installed JDK 6 from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 but it was not showing up in the Java section in System Preferences, but I looked up in the path /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin, and both java and javac were there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hint might help :
[10.6: Re-enable Java 1.4.2 and Java 1.5 apps in Snow Leopard](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100123192950640)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile against the 1.5 jdk with settings in javac.

In your case :

```
 javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5
```

You can even set this in your IDE. Or you can do this with maven and the `maven.compile.target` and `maven.compile.properties`

---

> **-source *release***
>
> Specifies the version of source code accepted. The following values for release are allowed:
>
> [...]
>
> - **1.5**
>     The compiler accepts code containing generics and other language features introduced in JDK 5.
>
> [...]

---

> **-target *version***
>
> Generate class files that target a specified version of the VM. Class files will run on the specified target and on later versions, but not on earlier versions of the VM. Valid targets are **1.1**  **1.2**  **1.3**  **1.4**  **1.5** (also **5**) and **1.6** (also **6**).
>   The default for **-target** depends on the value of **-source**:
>
> - If **-source** is not specified, the value of **-target** is **1.6**
> - If **-source** is **1.2**, the value of **-target** is **1.4**
> - If **-source** is **1.3**, the value of **-target** is **1.4**
>
> For all other values of -source, the value of **-target** is the value of **-source**.

---

**Resources :**

- [Javac 6 documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html)
- [Maven - Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't make your jdk or jre to run as version 5. Although it may solve some problems, all the libraries are still from the version 6.

Comment: You're right but I'm afraid there is nothing you can do for this.

Comment: Besides setting -source and -target, you need to grab the core library jar files (e.g., rt.jar, jce.jar, jsse.jar) of earlier jdk versions, and then set -bootclasspath to those files when using *javac*. Jar files from operating systems other than Mac usually also work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the problem with macs.
If you do backups, then you can just copy old folders containing jdk 5 from backup disk back to your machine. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use

> -target 1.5